# Razor-pages upload file by HttpClient with credentials

Tags: c#, httpclient, razor-pages

How can I upload file using HttpClient with credentials?
I'm trying to find some example/tutorial, but it's all unclear for me.
I want to upload file (image) from the form in Razor-pages on network disc by HttpClient, but I must be able to put my username and password - otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use **HttpClientHandler** class

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
// here your have to pass your handler to HttpClient constructor 
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: thanks, but have you got maybe full example of uploading anything with HttpClient? I didn't work with HttpClient before and I'm worry that HttpClientHandler is not enough for me handle with this